# How to insert array of data into table

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a table in frontend and need to put some data into the table. Below is what I am trying to achieve

```
____________________________________________________
| Product Name | Product Number | Product Location |
----------------------------------------------------
|       A      |       123      |      TEXAS       |
----------------------------------------------------
|       B      |       456      |      NEW YORK    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

However, I am keep getting like below table.

```
____________________________________________________
| Product Name | Product Number | Product Location |
----------------------------------------------------
|       A      |       123      |       TEXAS      |
                                       NEW YORK
----------------------------------------------------
|       B      |       456      |       TEXAS      |
                                       NEW YORK
----------------------------------------------------
```

Below is my code with JSX and render functions

```
    const getTheLocation = () => {
        return (
            productsHistoryLocation.map((productHistory) => (
                <p key={productHistory.product_id}>{productHistory.product_location}</p>
            ))
        )
    }

    const renderProducts = () => {
        return (
            productsData.map((product) => 
            (
                <tr key={product.product_number}>
                        <td>{products.bacs_unit}</td>
                        <td>{products.serial_number}</td>
                        <td>{getTheLocation()}</td>
                </tr>   
            ))
        )
    }
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Name</b></TableCell>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Number</b></TableCell>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Location</b></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {renderProducts()}
                    </TableBody>
             </Table>
```

Comment: You probably need to fetch `getTheLocation` method with some product-dependent variable. As per your code, it looks like `getTheLocation` will have elements for all the `productHistoryLocation`. If you can add some input data, it would be more clear.

Comment: You are showing all the rows with Product Location fetching the same data which is a collection i suppose, because your getTheLocation() function is using the map method.

Comment: Currently your ```renderProducts``` and ```getTheLocation``` are behaving as independent functions and as you have two locations, ```renderProducts``` is running ```getTheLocation``` for both of locations and thus the result. 

If the Location is somehow associated with the Product, you could pass in that associated index down to get location function and display only location associated to that particular product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your function `getTheLocation`  and possibly your data structure.

Change getTheLocation to

```
  const getTheLocation = (idx) => {
    const location = productsHistoryLocation.filter(
      (product) => product.product_id === idx
    );
    return <p key={idx}>{location[0].product_location}</p>;
  };
```

Check the working logic [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-star-w0xtx?file=/src/App.js):

Check the FULL CODE:

```
import "./styles.css";
import {
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell,
  TableBody
} from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const productsData = [
    {
      product_number: 1,
      bacs_unit: "A",
      serial_number: "123"
    },
    {
      product_number: 2,
      bacs_unit: "B",
      serial_number: "456"
    }
  ];

  const productsHistoryLocation = [
    {
      product_id: 1,
      product_location: "TEXAS"
    },
    {
      product_id: 2,
      product_location: "NEW YORK"
    }
  ];

  const getTheLocation = (idx) => {
    const location = productsHistoryLocation.filter(
      (product) => product.product_id === idx
    );
    return <p key={idx}>{location[0].product_location}</p>;
  };

  const renderProducts = () => {
    return productsData.map((product) => (
      <tr key={product.product_number}>
        <td>{product.bacs_unit}</td>
        <td>{product.serial_number}</td>
        <td>{getTheLocation(product.product_number)}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
              <b>Product Name</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <b>Product Number</b>
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <b>Product Location</b>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>{renderProducts()}</TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This code is working but when I refresh the page there is an error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_location' of undefined`

Comment: It is weird. If I return `<p>Texas</p>` everything works fine but doesn't work when I return `<p key={idx}>{location[0].product_location}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

pass key as parameter to other and direct use that key to get location

```
const getTheLocation = (key) => {
        return (
                <p >{productsHistoryLocation[key].product_location}</p>
        )
    }

    const renderProducts = () => {
        return (
            productsData.map((product, key) => 
            (
                <tr key={product.product_number}>
                        <td>{products.bacs_unit}</td>
                        <td>{products.serial_number}</td>
                        <td>{getTheLocation(key)}</td>
                </tr>   
            ))
        )
    }
        <Table aria-label="simple table">
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Name</b></TableCell>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Number</b></TableCell>
                            <TableCell><b>Product Location</b></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {renderProducts()}
                    </TableBody>
             </Table>
```

Comment: It worked at first but it says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'product_location' of undefined` as I reload the page

Comment: Maybe it is related to my other codes which fetches the data and useEffect...

Comment: I console logged key and productsHistoryLocation and commented out return statement and it is logging the data. However, when I put the return statement back it is getting a TypeError